# App runs different in simulator 4.2 than when first developed in xcode 3.00 and built in simulator 3

Tags: xcode, xcode4.2, ios-simulator

I developed my app in xcode 3. It ran fine in the simulator. I downloaded and installed xcode 4.2. I loaded the app and it had some build problems which xcode fixed and then I ran the build in the simulator and was successful.

The app worked fine but when I closed the app and relaunched it, it would stay on the screen that it last used before I closed it. In the simulator 3.00, it would always start again from the beginning of the app at the splash page and now in simulator 4.2 it goes to the screen it was on prior to when it was last closed.

Is there some code I need to add somewhere for it always to revert back to the beginning when it is relaunched?

Comment: more detailed information required. can't tell without codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add [**UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW23) to the info.plist;

> **UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend (Boolean - iOS)** specifies that the
>   application should be terminated rather than moved to the background
>   when it is quit. Applications linked against iPhone SDK 4.0 or later
>   can include this key and set its value to YES to prevent being
>   automatically opted-in to background execution and application
>   suspension. When the value of this key is YES, the application is 
>   terminated and purged from memory instead of moved to the background.
>   If this key is not present, or is set to NO, the application moves to
>   the background as usual.

Comment: perfecto... many thanks.. the apps running fine. thanks for your help